# HttpPost form submission error

Tags: java, html, forms, http-post

I'm trying to login to a grade database with HttpClient. I send it valid LogOnDetails.Username and LogOnDetails.Password information, but whenever I submit it consistently sends back errors. I'm not sure where it's happening, it may log in successfully and then hang up, or it may not even be making it in. here is the html it outputs after the request:

[output](http://www.mediafire.com/view/1wilw96u1m8o12k/output.txt)

and this is my code:

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://home-access.cfisd.net/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn");
    List<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LogOnDetails.Username", "s491670"));
    list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LogOnDetails.Password","qrrp4ji6t"));
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list));

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(new File("output.txt")));
    String line = null;
    while((line = file.readLine())!=null)
        pw.println(line);
    pw.close();
```

if anyone could shed some light on this, I'd love them forever. if HTML for the login form is needed let me know. thanks!

Comment: what kind of errors are you getting back? What's the statusCode (`response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()`) and what's the message (`response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase()`)?

Comment: 500, internal server error Alexander

Comment: @user2659185, you should remove your username and password from the question, then flag it as "other" to ask a moderator to remove the edit history.

Comment: Also you should change your password immediately for that account.

Comment: @Alexander, please don't do it on his behalf ;P

Comment: Hey, everybody who's commented here has been super helpful. I'd upvote you all but I don't have enough reputation to do so yet. I just haven't picked solutions yet because i haven't 100% solved the problem yet. Close though.

Comment: Problem solved. just did as everyone suggested, did some work with cookies and redirection, now its working perfectly. I love you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the form submits the following form data is sent:

```
Form Data
Database:10
LogOnDetails.UserName:sadf
LogOnDetails.Password:sdf
```

Add the following:

```
list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Database", "10")); // or 20
```

As you are well aware I can't test this.

Comment: `As you are well aware I can't test this.` ??? I can test it. The URL is accessible.

Comment: Well, I don't know if the username and password in the question are correct (I really hope), they probably aren't but I am not going to try them either. Perhaps `can't` should be `won't` ;)

Comment: I've tested it (see below) ^^

Comment: I just put in the edit you suggested, and it changed my output to:        302
Found
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/HomeAccess/">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>                                                                                                        Any idea what that means?

Comment: @user2659185, it looks like it worked, you will have to persist cookies for subsequent calls and if you chose follow the redirects. See Alexander's answer.

Comment: I'm a bit inexperienced with this. Would you mind explaining how you knew what was sent with the form data, and the significance of the line you added?

Comment: Also could you run by me how to manage cookies. If it's not too lengthy of a process?

Answer (score 1):

If you add @robbmj's patch, you do not get the 500 error page, but a 302 (moved), which is a good start:

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/HomeAccess/">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

You can advise the http-client to handle redirects by itself, but depending on the version of http-client, handling redirects is done differently (they're always refactoring this code). Which version are you using?

Maybe the `302` means that it was all successful and I'm logged in now. ;)

Headers returned:

```
Cache-Control : private
Content-Type : text/html; charset=utf-8
Location : /HomeAccess/
Server : Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version : 4.0
X-AspNet-Version : 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie : ASP.NET_SessionId=hvjw3jqjoaa5ohofaaxu4od1; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie : .AuthCookie=; expires=Tue, 12-Oct-1999 05:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie : .AuthCookie=0863B972684CC784E4D9D5594354B6F08FF6FF7225836F01A9715D0ABA633042946B032987F7926588610F5FB7C18757CE759338B75E341DF56DB3FB71BC326B3D6E49EA94EEE43B39FCC84BB98F236CA0D63CE668E14434169C6B835FA671DD; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By : ASP.NET
Date : Thu, 12 Mar 2015 23:37:12 GMT
Content-Length : 129
```

Comment: I guess the 302 means the login is successful, did it give you a session cookie?